# Custom wrapper for id key

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design, identity

I want to wrap id in custom class. Like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @EmbeddedId
    UserId id;
}
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {
    private Long value;
}
```

The issue in auto generation `value` for `UserId`.  What I should do to make `@GeneratedValue` on `value` be workable?

BTW, It would be great if `id` would be initialized automatically itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Hibernate only generates values for a field marked as the @Id. I found [this](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393944&sid=57b20ef2c7de6f6bcba632130987bc22) post and Hardy's answer supports this.

We have tried to do similar and managed it via a pre-insert listener. It was fairly complex and non-ideal though. Also you might find different behaviour on different database palatforms. Using Oracle sequences would mean that you need to assign the value pre-insert (Hibernate does a select to get the value and then an insert) but with MySQL the auto incrementing field would assign the value and hibernate does an insert to generate the auto generated value and then select to find out what the value was.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's pretty weird that such feature isn't supported since it can be common used.